# Filtering vector by values with filter()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm filtering my experiment data, I want to get all the rows were the time is between 180 - 1800 seconds.

I use `filter()` like this:

```
dat = dat %>%
  filter(Duration..in.seconds. > 180) %>%
  filter(Duration..in.seconds.  < 1800)
```

The first filter works well, but the second one filters all the data, which is wrong, here is the vector :

```
dat$Duration..in.seconds.
[1] "114"  "188"  "453"  "114"  "188"  "453"  "114"  "188"  "453"  "188"  "453"  "2000"
[13] "2000" "1900"
```

as you see, the second filter is suppose to filter only 2 rows.
Can you spot the problem?

Comment: What is the output of `class(dat$Duration..in.seconds.)`? It must be numeric but the example implies a character which can not be filtered using a numeric condition.

Comment: looks like you are filtering strings by a numeric value.  try `mutate(Duration..in.seconds.  = as.numeric(Duration..in.seconds.))` before filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your data is in `characters`, so to filter that you first have to convert that to `numeric`. After that you can filter the conditions using one `filter` function with `&` operation. You can use the following code:

```
dat <- data.frame(Duration..in.seconds. = c("114",  "188",  "453",  "114" , "188" , "453" , "114" , "188" , "453" , "188" , "453",  "2000" ,"2000" ,"1900" ))

library(dplyr)

dat = dat %>%
  mutate(Duration..in.seconds. = as.numeric(Duration..in.seconds.)) %>%
  filter(Duration..in.seconds. > 180 & Duration..in.seconds.  < 1800)
```

Output:

```
 Duration..in.seconds.
1                   188
2                   453
3                   188
4                   453
5                   188
6                   453
7                   188
8                   453
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
## Loading the library
library(dplyr)

## Loading the data
dat = data.frame(Duration..in.seconds. = c("114",  "188",  "453",  "114" , "188" , "453" , "114" , "188" , "453" , "188" , "453",  "2000" ,"2000" ,"1900" ))

## Filtering
dat %>%
  filter(Duration..in.seconds. %in% c(180:1800))

  Duration..in.seconds.
1                   188
2                   453
3                   188
4                   453
5                   188
6                   453
7                   188
8                   453
```

Comment: What does the `%in%` operation do?

Comment: @EyalKatz This is used to filter all those elements that are present in c(180:1800).